# Rails 4 create a child dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent dropdown:

`<%= select_tag "Categories", options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select Categories"%>`

I am new in rails.I have a parent dropdown `Categories`.I want to create a child dropdown such that when i select a category from parent dropdown , i will see it's respective `sub-categories` in the child dropdown.

Comment: you need javascript to populate your child select

Comment: can i do it without use of javascript in rails.By using ruby code.

Comment: No you can't. Ruby is server side.You want your child select to contain subcategories based on parent categories or in simple words you want to dynamically manipulate your DOM element and this is what js is for

Comment: can u give me some reference for this.I don't know much more about javascript.It will be helpful for me.

Comment: checkout this http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus